# Codeigniter: pagination is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

First page it shows without error but When I click to '2' page button in pagination It gives this error:
If someone could please look over this code, and tell me why it's not working. Thank you in advance.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> Erreur de syntaxe près de ''20', 20' à la ligne 1
>
> `SELECT * FROM avto WHERE category = 'yengil' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '20', 20`
>
> Filename: D:/wamp/www/avtosavdo.uz/application/models/News_model.php
>
> Line Number: 30

Here my controller code:

```
            public function prisepNews()
    {
            $this->pagination('prisepnews', 'prisep');
            $title['title'] = 'Прицеп';
            $this->load->view('templates/navbar', $title);
            $this->load->view('news/allNews', $data);
    }

            public function pagination($url, $value)
    {
           $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/news/'.$url.'/';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->news_model->record_count($value);
            $config['per_page'] = 20;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['num_links'] = 3;
            $config['first_link'] = 'Биринчи';
            $config['last_link'] = 'Охирги';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Кейинги';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Олдинги';
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($config['per_page'], $page, $value);
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            return $data;
    }
```

Here my model code:

```
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM avto WHERE category = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($category, $start, $limit));

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
            return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quotes in `LIMIT '20'` create Problem.

You need to change  query to

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where("category",$category);
$this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
$query = $this->db->get('avto', $limit, $start);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: thanks it works, but it should be changed order to order_by and places of $start, $limit to $limit, $start